# How to run mysql in Django 1.5.5 with Python 3.3.4 in Windows 7

Tags: python, mysql, django

I want to run mysql in Django 1.5.5 with python 3.3.4 in Windows 7. I did that:

After instal python, django I install mysql-connector-python-1.1.6-py3.3.msi from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

Then I edit in Django project settings.py like that:

```
DATABASES = {
 'default': {
        'NAME': 'mydatabasename',
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypass',
        'OPTIONS': {
        'autocommit': True,
       },
    }
}
```

Then When I try to run django with manage.py runserver I have this error track:

```
C:\projects\myproject>manage.py runserver
Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <dja
ngo.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x000000
000313D780>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.
py", line 93, in inner_run
self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 280,
in validate
   num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\validation.py", lin
e 28, in get_validation_errors
from django.db import models, connection
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 40, in <modul
e>
backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 34, in __geta
ttr__
 return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __getitem
__
  conn = backend.DatabaseWrapper(db, alias)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\django\base.py", line 471,
in __init__
self._connect()
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\django\base.py", line 542,
in _connect
 self.init_connection_state()
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\django\base.py", line 531,
in init_connection_state
 if self.settings_dict['AUTOCOMMIT']:
KeyError: 'AUTOCOMMIT'
Exception ResourceWarning: ResourceWarning('unclosed <socket.socket object, fd=3
48, family=2, type=1, prot
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You need to install MySQL-python. Use the following command:

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

Alternatively you could use [pymysql](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/).

Answer (score 0):

You should first install mysql-pyton (if you don't have pip on your windows you can use exe file from this site https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.4)

And than read the documenation becauase you have wrong configuration https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit this file: `C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\django\base.py`

Go to this line: `if self.settings_dict['AUTOCOMMIT']:`
            `self.set_autocommit(self.settings_dict['AUTOCOMMIT'])` and comment both the lines.

This solution worked for me on Windows 7 home using Python 3.3 and Django 1.5.2

Answer (score 0):

I think your config is uncorrect .

This works for me, you can try:

> try this for **MySQL Connector** that working in django:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'mydatabasename',
    'USER': 'myuser',
    'PASSWORD': 'mypass',
    'HOST': 'myhost',
    'PORT': 'myport',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'autocommit': True,
    },
}
```

}

> or try this for **MySQL Connector pool** that working in django:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'PyMysqlPool.mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME': 'mydatabasename',
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypass',
        'HOST': 'myhost',
        'PORT': 'myport',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'autocommit': True,
            'pool': {
                #use = 0 no pool else use pool
                "use":0,
                # size is >=0,  0 is dynamic pool
                "size":10,
                #pool name
                "name":"local",
            }
        },
    }
}
```